# Return row with most matching parameters

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make a stored procedure who will return me the `RowID` with most matching parameters. Let's say we have a table:

```
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
| RowID | DocumentID | EmployeeID | CompanyID |
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
|     1 |         36 | 1          | 4         |
|     2 |         36 | null       | 2         |
|     3 |         36 | 4          | null      |
+-------+------------+------------+-----------+
```

And I send let's say values `DocumentID = 36` ,`EmployeeID = 5`, `ComanyID = 2`,
it should return me second row since `DocumentID` and `CompanyID` exist.

Some other situation would be, if I send `DocumentID = 36`, `EmployeeID = 5` and `CompanyID=10`, it should return me first in the table.

If there is too little information about this problem, or it's not clear, feel free to ask for more detail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
;WITH c AS
(
  SELECT RowID, 
    c = CASE WHEN DocumentID = @DocumentID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN EmployeeID = @EmployeeID THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
      + CASE WHEN CompanyID  = @CompanyID  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT TOP (1) RowID FROM c ORDER BY c DESC;
```

Comment: Additionally, changing the substituted value (instead of 1) in the CASE statement will allow sorting based on different weights for the fields.

Comment: Elegant and readable, just the way I like it. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this - but see if you can understand the concept.

```
SELECT TOP (1) RowID
FROM
(
SELECT RowID
FROM YourTable
WHERE DocumentID = @DocumentID
UNION ALL
SELECT RowID
FROM YourTable
WHERE EmployeeID = @EmployeeID
UNION ALL
SELECT RowID
FROM YourTable
WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID
) r
GROUP BY RowID
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC, RowID ASC;
```